# SerializeArray() Return all Items in a Multiple Select Box

Tags: jquery

I need `serializeArray()` to return all items in the selection box every time and not just the currently selected item(s) as the content of my selectionBox can grow or shrink.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="selectionBox" >
   <option value="email1@test.com">Test1</option>
   <option value="email2@test.com">Test2</option>
   <option value="email3@test.com">Test3</option>
   <option value="email4@test.com">Test4</option>
   <option value="email5@test.com">Test5</option>
</select>
```

...

```
//Select 1 item in the select list box
formArray = $("#selectionBox").serializeArray();
alert(formArray.length);  // this will be 1

//Select 5 items in the select list box
formArray = $("#selectionBox").serializeArray();
alert(formArray.length);  // this will be 5
```

I need it to always return the full 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `serializeArray` just serializes those values that will be sent by the form. If you want all the options, you will have to code it yourself, like this:

```
var arr = [], $select = $("#selectionBox"), name = $select.attr("name");
$select.find("option").each(function() {
    arr[arr.length] = { name: name, value: this.value };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function indeed returns only "successful" controls, see [jQuery.serializeArray Api](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). As a workaround you could cache which ones are selected, then select all, then reset the state to your cached values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to code it. The example below

html:

```
<form id="testForm">
    <select multiple="multiple" id="selectionBox" name="selectionBox[]">
        <option value="email1@test.com">Test1</option>
        <option value="email2@test.com">Test2</option>
        <option value="email3@test.com">Test3</option>
        <option value="email4@test.com">Test4</option>
        <option value="email5@test.com">Test5</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#testForm").submit(function (event) {
    console.log($("#selectionBox").serializeArray());
    // output: [ {name: "selectionBox[]", value: ***}, ... ]

    $.post("/path/to/send", $(this).serializeArray()).always(console.log.bind(console));
});
```